# Assigning event handlers in a for loop only applies to last iteration

Tags: javascript, powerbi, dom-events

I am embedding content from Power BI into my web app, and would like to apply event handlers to each piece. This is my ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var embededTiles = [];

        for (index = 0; index < configs.length; index++) {
            var container = document.getElementsByClassName('powerbi-embed')[index];

            embededTiles.push(powerbi.embed(container, configs[index]));
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < embededTiles.length; i++) {
            var tileEmbed = embededTiles[i];


            tileEmbed.off("tileLoaded");
            tileEmbed.on("tileLoaded", function (event) {
                console.log("tile " + i + " loaded");
            });

            tileEmbed.off("tileClicked");
            tileEmbed.on("tileClicked", function (event) {
                console.log(event);
                location.href = "/powerbi/report?reportId=" + event.detail.openReport.reportId;
            });
        }

    });
```

In the second for loop the "tileLoaded" and "tileClicked" events only apply to the last item in the array

Comment: Did you try debugging in the devtools by keeping breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I've been here before.  Here are 2 days you can fix this problem.

#### Cleanest Way

Use `.forEach` rather than a `for` loop.  Like this:

```js
    embededTiles.forEach( function(tileEmbed, i){

      tileEmbed.off("tileLoaded");
      tileEmbed.on("tileLoaded", function (event) {
        console.log("tile " + i + " loaded");
      });

      tileEmbed.off("tileClicked");
      tileEmbed.on("tileClicked", function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        location.href = "/powerbi/report?reportId=" + event.detail.openReport.reportId;
      });

    })
```

#### Revising what you had tried using a *closure*

The issue is that your loop loops through all of `i` before your event handler is fired.  So by the time an `embedded` tile fires a `tileLoaded` or `tileClicked` event, your loop has already run all the way until `i` is the value of the length of your array.  That is why only the last one works.  In order to fix this, you need a *closure*.  Like this:

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < embededTiles.length; i++) {

       ((j) => {

         var tileEmbed = embededTiles[j];

         tileEmbed.off("tileLoaded");
         tileEmbed.on("tileLoaded", function (event) {
            console.log("tile " + j + " loaded");
         });

         tileEmbed.off("tileClicked");
         tileEmbed.on("tileClicked", function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            location.href = "/powerbi/report?reportId=" + event.detail.openReport.reportId;
         });

       })(i)  

    }
```

What this does is create an immediately invoked functional expression inside your loop, with a new index variable `j`.  For each iteration of your loops, `j` is run, with the value `i` for that iteration.  But the value of `i` at that moment is closed off and saved into your event handler, for each iteration.  So now each item of your array has its own event handler associated with its index in the array.

Comment: So i replace my for loop with your foreach, but I'm still getting the same results where only the last tile has the events

Comment: I've been playing around with [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-handlers-from-loop-jquery-rhqkw) and I have not been able to reproduce your problem.  Perhaps you could whip up a working example of the problem we could edit / play with?